# The pagingtoolbar EXTJS 4 doesn't show pages correctly in the grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I set pagesize = 2, for example, but the pagingtoolbar always shows the total number of the results. For example: "1 of 30" when it should show 2 in a page. The grid shows two rows correctly, but the tbar shows this message and the navigation button is disabled. Has someone a similar problem about this, or a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the pageSize on the store: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-pageSize during it's creation.

```
var store = Ext.create('Your.data.Store', {
    pageSize: 2
});
```